# Rounding positive/negative numbers to nearest "whole" number

Tags: python, integer, python-2.x, cmath

I'm trying to round numbers derived from cmath's divide function to a "whole" number, the results often being negative due to the nature of the program.

Example code:

```
strength = input("Input Strength Stat: ")
str_mod = round(strength/2)
```

However, the result of this is that it, due to an oddity in python, always returns closer to zero rather than further if, say `str_mod` prior to rounding ends up at something like -1.5 (resulting in -1 rather than -2 as desired)

This, since I'm trying to create an automatic derived stat calc script for a custom Pen and Paper RPG system, is not the desired behavior. What I desire is for the script to return, at -1.5, -2.0 upon rounding. I need to be able to do this while still rounding positive numbers up similarly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this the safe way:

```
strength = float(raw_input("Input Strength Stat:"))
str_mod = round(strength/2)
```

In this case, since strength is guaranteed to be a float, you can safely divide by 2 without worrying about truncation or importing `division` from `__future__`.  As a bonus, you remove a huge security liability in your game as well.

Using input, a user could do some serious damage to your system:

```
RPG console> Input Strength Stat: __import__('os').system('rm -r ~')
                                 #^ User input (don't try this!)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. I'll have to remember this, as I'm just learning python.

Comment: wouldnt this only apply if you were to `eval` it?

Comment: @JoranBeasley -- The OP is using python 2.x as evidenced by the lack of true division and that the return value of `input` is apparently an `int`.  In python 2.x, `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(...))`

Comment: ahhh thats good to know.  I never used input and didnt realize that it eval'd the input

Answer (score 4):

this is because you are getting a(truncated) int from `strength/2`

try `strength/2.0`

this is not an oddity with python but simply how most languages cast types for numbers

5/2 = 2

5/2.0 = 2.5

Comment: or `from __future__ import division`

Comment: yeah ... but still its better he understands some bit of numeric casting for any other language he might deal with

Comment: (+1) Nice work figuring out what the actual problem was.  Sometimes these problems with `input` are a little difficult because of the type differences between python2 and python3.  You nailed this one pretty fast though.

Comment: This was ultimately the best answer, but unfortunately less useful than the one just under it that points out a major security flaw in my program, and how to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) to get the same rounding as RPG. With Decimal, you can set the rounding mode to [up, down, half up, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10826537/298607)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could try:

`from __future__ import division`

in order to use py3k division. (e.g. result will be always float)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem right, you'd like something that will [round half away from zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_half_away_from_zero), as:

-0.5 -> -1

0.5 -> 1

[These folks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689594/how-to-round-away-from-0-in-python-3-x) have some good answers. In particular, I based my answer below on [AGN Gazer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8033585/agn-gazer)'s answer:

```
from math import floor, ceil

strength = float(raw_input("Input Strength Stat:"))
str_mod  = floor((strength/2) + 0.5) if strength  >= 0.0 else ceil((strength/2)  - 0.5)
```

Thanks [AGN Gazer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8033585/agn-gazer)!