# How to round away from 0 in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 2 [rounding](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) is done away from `0`, so, for example, `round(0.5)` is `1.0`.
In Python 3.x, however, [rounding](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) is done toward the even choice, so `round(0.5)`  is `0`.
What function can I use in Python 3.x to get the old behavior?

Comment: Do you really want the Python 2 rounding behaviour? The behaviour is pretty complex https://stackoverflow.com/a/22155830/6260170

Comment: You should make clear that you're referring only to rounding of values ending in `.5`.

Answer (score 9):

If your code is not particularly performance sensitive, you can use the standard `decimal` library to achieve the result you want. `Decimal().quantize()` allows choosing the rounding method:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP
result = float(Decimal(0.5).quantize(Decimal(0), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP))
print(result)  # Will output 1.0
```

Answer (score 5):

Equivalent of Python 2.7 `round()` when rounding to an integer (one-parameter):

```
import math
def py2round(x):
    if x >= 0.0:
        return math.floor(x + 0.5)
    else:
        return math.ceil(x - 0.5)
```

Another option that is more succinct but more expensive for scalar values:

```
def py2round(x):
    return int(math.copysign(math.floor(abs(x) + 0.5), x))
```

It is however much more performant for large vectors if `math` is replaced with `numpy` (but very slow for scalars):

```
import numpy as np
def py2round(x):
    return np.copysign(np.floor(abs(x) + 0.5), x).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the Python 2 rounding behavior in Python 3 for the one-argument form of `round()` you can use a custom function like this:

```
def myround(n):
    if round(n + 1) - round(n) == 1:
        return float(round(n))
    return n + abs(n) / n * 0.5
```

Demo:

```
>>> myround(0.5)
1.0
>>> myround(1.5)
2.0
>>> myround(-0.5)
-1.0
>>> myround(-1.5)
-2.0
>>> myround(1)
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def round_up(x):
    aX = abs(x)
    return math.ceil(aX)*(aX/x)
```

This solution might work for you.

For x = -1.2 `round_up(x) = -2`, x = 2.3 `round_up(x) = 3` etc.

edit: this solution will crash for x = 0. you can change the return value to

```
return math.ceil(aX)*(aX/x) if x is not 0 else 0
```

Comment: if you want to get -1 for x = -1.2 just use math.ceil function

Answer (score 0):

According to [CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/floatobject.c#L1109),

> The basic idea is very simple: convert and round the double to a
>   decimal string using _Py_dg_dtoa, then convert that decimal string
>   back to a double with _Py_dg_strtod.  There's one minor difficulty:
>   Python 2.x expects round to do round-half-away-from-zero, while
>   _Py_dg_dtoa does round-half-to-even.  So we need some way to detect and correct the halfway cases.

If you care about the performance, consider copying the relevant C code and import as an extension. But if you don't care, here's a Python implementation:

```
def myround(a):
    num = str(a)
    num = str.split('.', 1)
    if int(num[1][0]) >= 5:
        return int(num[0]) + 1 if a > 0 else int(num[0]) - 1
    else:
        return int(num[0]) - 1 if a > 0 else int(num[0]) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much like the other solutions, but using a shorthand *if* statement instead of a function:

```
    segments = ceil(gamma / 90) if gamma > 0 else floor(gamma/90)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
f = lambda i:i-i%(1|-(i>0))

print(f('your float number'))
```

hope be useful!

Comment: This looks like it rounds to the nearest infinity, not to the nearest whole like python 2 does it, the question was specifically concerned about the beheaviour with `.5`.

You can also provide more context on how exactly the function does the rounding.

Answer (score 0):

For positive numbers the following works for me:

```
>>> import math
>>> x = 0.5
>>> (math.trunc(x*2)+1) >> 1
1
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a possible solution I've come up with:

```
import math

def round_away_from_zero(x):
    a = abs(x)
    r = math.floor(a) + math.floor(2 * (a % 1))
    return r if x >= 0 else -r
```

Tests:

```
round_away_from_zero(0.5)
# 1
round_away_from_zero(1.5)
# 2
round_away_from_zero(2.5)
# 3
round_away_from_zero(-0.5)
# -1
round_away_from_zero(-1.5)
# -2
round_away_from_zero(-2.5)
# -3
```