# Floor or Ceiling away from zero in Python

Tags: python-3.x, rounding, floor, ceil

Using Python 3, is there a more Pythonic way to floor/ceil as float away from zero than doing this:

```
import math

def away_from_zero(x):
    if x > 0:
        return int(math.ceil(x))
    else:
        return int(math.floor(x))
```

Is there a better (perhaps more elegant) way to get the nearest integer with greater absolute magnitude?

Comment: Pythonic? Nope.

Comment: If you mean by not using `math.floor` or `math.ceil` then yes, just use the built-in `round` function , if it is negative you return `round(x-1)` else you return `round(x+1)`

Comment: FWIW: `int(math.copysign(1, x))*math.ceil(abs(x)) `

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Except being horribly slow, this is the most interesting solution.

Comment: Crypto-pythonic: `[math.floor, math.ceil][x > 0](x)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round away from 0 in Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689594/how-to-round-away-from-0-in-python-3-x)

Comment: @Tomerikoo No. This is not a question about "rounding".

Comment: `floor` and `ceil` are rounding methods. You are asking about a specific strategy for rounding, whether you know it or not...

Comment: BTW, the first answer of the link I gave you does exactly what you want with `ROUND_UP` instead of `ROUND_HALF_UP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not necessarily consider this more Pythonic, but if you'd like to avoid invoking the `math.floor` and `math.ceiling` functions and are looking for something more algebraic, you could do something like this:

```py
def away_from_zero(x):

    return int(x // 1 + 2 ** (x > 0) - 1)
```

**As an explanation:**

The integer division `x // 1` will round down any floating point number, negative or positive, to the nearest integer that's less than `x`. So `1.5` goes to `1.0` and `-1.5` goes to `-2.0`. This alone solves the problem for negative values and whole numbers, but positive non-integers are off-by-one.

To account for the positive case, we want to offset the result by `1` when `x` is positive but not when it's negative. You *could* use conditional logic for this, but if you want to restrict the computation to a single equation, you could also add some term that equals `1` when `x` is positive and `0` when `x` is negative. To that end, we have `2 ** (x > 0) - 1`. Here, when `x` is positive, we have

```py
>>> 2 ** True - 1
1
```

When `x` is negative, we have

```py
>>> 2 ** False - 1
0
```

Finally, since integer division of a `float` returns a `float`, we cast the result to an `int`, which gives the desired behavior:

```py
>>> away_from_zero(1.4)
2
>>> away_from_zero(1.6)
2
>>> away_from_zero(-1.4)
-2
>>> away_from_zero(-1.6)
-2
```

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant way of writing the function you already have would be:

```py
import math

def away_from_zero(x):
    return int(math.floor(x) if x > 0 else math.ceil(x))
```