# Python3 - Round up combination like this

Tags: python-3.x, math, decimal, rounding

I have a float number combination (min_number, max_number),and I am expecting the following round up:

```
(-19.12, 34.45) "rounded to" (-19.2, 34.5)
(-0.34, -0.22) "rounded to" (-0.4, -0.3)
(-0.58, -0.87) "rounded to" (-0.6, -0.9)
(-0.24, 5.98) "rounded to" (-0.3, 6.0)
(2.57, 22.38) "rounded to" (2.6, 22.4)
```

Note that only 1 decimal place is required. And then:

```
size = int(input('please input: '))
number = (min_number + max_number) / size
```

Then "number" will need to be rounded as well, also require 1 decimal place:

```
10.233333 "rounded to" 10.3
5.744542267888 "rounded to" 5.8
```

Any thoughts? Many thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round away from 0 in Python 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689594/how-to-round-away-from-0-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just multiply by 10, round and divide by 10

```
import math
num = input("Round a number:")
num = num.split()
print( math.ceil( float(num[0]) * 10 ) / 10,  math.ceil( float(num[1]) * 10 ) / 10 )
```

**Note:** As @0 0 pointed out this will not work for negative numbers if you want to round negative numbers then you will need to add an if statement for them and use `math.floor`

Comment: Thanks Yash, I still have issue, can you see my latest post?

Comment: Ok I'll check it out

Comment: Why `num[0]`? That will just take the first character of the input string, so if the input is `12.34`, it will just use `1`. If you are instead referring to the tuples as in the question, then the input should be changed.

Comment: Note that this does not round away from zero for negative numbers. Using the very first example from the question, `-19.12`, `math.ceil( float(-19.12) * 10 ) / 10` results in `-19.1`, not `-19.2`.

Comment: I was using the tuple as an input

Comment: Any input you'd use would be a string (that is, `num` would be a string); how would you input tuples then?

Comment: @00 Sorry fixed it