# Round float to x decimals?

Tags: python, math, rounding

Is there a way to round a python float to x decimals? For example:

```
>>> x = roundfloat(66.66666666666, 4)
66.6667
>>> x = roundfloat(1.29578293, 6)
1.295783
```

I've found ways to trim/truncate them (66.666666666 --> 66.6666), but not round (66.666666666 --> 66.6667).

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use the built-in function `round()`:

```
In [23]: round(66.66666666666,4)
Out[23]: 66.6667

In [24]: round(1.29578293,6)
Out[24]: 1.295783
```

help on `round()`:

> round(number[, ndigits]) -> floating point number
>
> Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits (default 0
>   digits). This always returns a floating point number.  Precision may
>   be negative.

Comment: I hate the idea I like this simple answer, while knowing the explanation provided by @mark-dickinson is valid.

Answer (score 179):

I feel compelled to provide a counterpoint to Ashwini Chaudhary's answer.  Despite appearances, the two-argument form of the `round` function *does not* round a Python float to a given number of decimal places, and it's often not the solution you want, even when you think it is. Let me explain...

The ability to round a (Python) float to some number of decimal places is something that's frequently requested, but turns out to be rarely what's actually needed.  The beguilingly simple answer `round(x, number_of_places)` is something of an attractive nuisance: it *looks* as though it does what you want, but thanks to the fact that Python floats are stored internally in binary, it's doing something rather subtler.  Consider the following example:

```
>>> round(52.15, 1)
52.1
```

With a naive understanding of what `round` does, this looks wrong:  surely it should be rounding *up* to `52.2` rather than *down* to `52.1`?  To understand why such behaviours can't be relied upon, you need to appreciate that while this looks like a simple decimal-to-decimal operation, it's far from simple.

So here's what's *really* happening in the example above. (*deep breath*) We're displaying a *decimal* representation of the nearest *binary* floating-point number to the nearest `n`-digits-after-the-point *decimal* number to a *binary* floating-point approximation of a numeric literal written in *decimal*.  So to get from the original numeric literal to the displayed output, the underlying machinery has made *four* separate conversions between binary and decimal formats, two in each direction.  Breaking it down (and with the usual disclaimers about assuming IEEE 754 binary64 format, round-ties-to-even rounding, and IEEE 754 rules):

1. First the numeric literal `52.15` gets parsed and converted to a Python float.  The actual number stored is `7339460017730355 * 2**-47`, or `52.14999999999999857891452847979962825775146484375`.
2. Internally as the first step of the `round` operation, Python computes the closest 1-digit-after-the-point decimal string to the stored number.  Since that stored number is a touch under the original value of `52.15`, we end up rounding down and getting a string `52.1`.  This explains why we're getting `52.1` as the final output instead of `52.2`.
3. Then in the second step of the `round` operation, Python turns that string back into a float, getting the closest binary floating-point number to `52.1`, which is now `7332423143312589 * 2**-47`, or `52.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625`.
4. Finally, as part of Python's read-eval-print loop (REPL), the floating-point value is displayed (in decimal).  That involves converting the binary value back to a decimal string, getting `52.1` as the final output.

In Python 2.7 and later, we have the pleasant situation that the two conversions in step 3 and 4 cancel each other out.  That's due to Python's choice of `repr` implementation, which produces the shortest decimal value guaranteed to round correctly to the actual float.  One consequence of that choice is that if you start with any (not too large, not too small) decimal literal with 15 or fewer significant digits then the corresponding float will be displayed showing those exact same digits:

```
>>> x = 15.34509809234
>>> x
15.34509809234
```

Unfortunately, this furthers the illusion that Python is storing values in decimal.  Not so in Python 2.6, though! Here's the original example executed in Python 2.6:

```
>>> round(52.15, 1)
52.200000000000003
```

Not only do we round in the opposite direction, getting `52.2` instead of `52.1`, but the displayed value doesn't even print as `52.2`!  This behaviour has caused numerous reports to the Python bug tracker along the lines of "round is broken!".  But it's not `round` that's broken, it's user expectations.  (Okay, okay, `round` is a *little* bit broken in Python 2.6, in that it doesn't use correct rounding.)

Short version: if you're using two-argument round, and you're expecting predictable behaviour from a *binary* approximation to a *decimal* round of a *binary* approximation to a *decimal* halfway case, you're asking for trouble.

So enough with the "two-argument round is bad" argument.  What *should* you be using instead?  There are a few possibilities, depending on what you're trying to do.

- If you're rounding for display purposes, then you don't want a float result at all;  you want a string.  In that case the answer is to use string formatting:

  ```
  >>> format(66.66666666666, '.4f')
  '66.6667'
  >>> format(1.29578293, '.6f')
  '1.295783'
  ```

  Even then, one has to be aware of the internal binary representation in order not to be surprised by the behaviour of apparent decimal halfway cases.

  ```
  >>> format(52.15, '.1f')
  '52.1'
  ```
- If you're operating in a context where it matters which direction decimal halfway cases are rounded (for example, in some financial contexts), you might want to represent your numbers using the `Decimal` type.  Doing a decimal round on the `Decimal` type makes a lot more sense than on a binary type (equally, rounding to a fixed number of binary places makes perfect sense on a binary type).  Moreover, the `decimal` module gives you better control of the rounding mode.  In Python 3, `round` does the job directly.  In Python 2, you need the `quantize` method.

  ```
  >>> Decimal('66.66666666666').quantize(Decimal('1e-4'))
  Decimal('66.6667')
  >>> Decimal('1.29578293').quantize(Decimal('1e-6'))
  Decimal('1.295783')
  ```
- In rare cases, the two-argument version of `round` really *is* what you want: perhaps you're binning floats into bins of size `0.01`, and you don't particularly care which way border cases go.  However, these cases are rare, and it's difficult to justify the existence of the two-argument version of the `round` builtin based on those cases alone.

Comment: Another route. Ignoring float(), what is this notation called? float('%.2f' % 1.29578293). That produces 1.3, it drops the zero. Or float('%.3f' % 1.29578293) is 1.296

Comment: @gseattle: As of Python 3, using fixed-precision formatting and then converting to `float` should be entirely equivalent to using `round`. The formatting operation is again a conversion from binary floating-point to a decimal string, and it's using exactly the same machinery under the hood that `round` is using. (For Python 2, it's a bit different, because the half-way behaviour is different.)

Comment: As for **MicroPython**, this topic is [discussed here](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/3516).

Comment: Hi Mark. Since you seem to be very knowledgeable in floating-point arithmetic, would you like to share your expertise on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59913076/2326961)?

Answer (score 1):

Default rounding in python and numpy:

```py
In: [round(i) for i in np.arange(10) + .5]
Out: [0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10]
```

I used this to get integer rounding to be applied to a pandas series:

`import decimal`

and use this line to set the rounding to "half up" a.k.a rounding as taught in school:
`decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP`

Finally I made this function to apply it to a pandas series object

```py
def roundint(value):
    return value.apply(lambda x: int(decimal.Decimal(x).to_integral_value()))
```

So now you can do `roundint(df.columnname)`

And for numbers:

```py
In: [int(decimal.Decimal(i).to_integral_value()) for i in np.arange(10) + .5]
Out: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Credit: [kares](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607477/4289062)

Answer (score 0):

The Mark Dickinson answer, although complete, didn't work with the float(52.15) case. After some tests, there is the solution that I'm using:

```
import decimal
        
def value_to_decimal(value, decimal_places):
    decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP  # define rounding method
    return decimal.Decimal(str(float(value))).quantize(decimal.Decimal('1e-{}'.format(decimal_places)))
```

(The conversion of the 'value' to float and then string is very important, that way, 'value' can be of the type float, decimal, integer or string!)

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Using the above function with 2.5,0 gives the output as 2 which is the same as default behaviour. Is it what is expected?

Comment: Thank you Canute S, I used this method mostly for 2 decimal places (currencies) and seems that is not working properly for 0 decimal places

Comment: @CanuteS If you find a fully working solution please share with us!

Comment: This code can't be formatted properly so posting as answer below

Comment: @CanuteS thanks! the "decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP" does the trick! I will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I coded a function (used in Django project for DecimalField) but it can be used in Python project :

This code :

- Manage **integers digits** to avoid too high number
- Manage **decimals digits** to avoid too low number
- Manage **signed and unsigned** numbers

Code with tests :

```
def convert_decimal_to_right(value, max_digits, decimal_places, signed=True):

    integer_digits = max_digits - decimal_places
    max_value = float((10**integer_digits)-float(float(1)/float((10**decimal_places))))

    if signed:
        min_value = max_value*-1
    else:
        min_value = 0

    if value > max_value:
        value = max_value

    if value < min_value:
        value = min_value

    return round(value, decimal_places)


value = 12.12345
nb = convert_decimal_to_right(value, 4, 2)
# nb : 12.12

value = 12.126
nb = convert_decimal_to_right(value, 4, 2)
# nb : 12.13

value = 1234.123
nb = convert_decimal_to_right(value, 4, 2)
# nb : 99.99

value = -1234.123
nb = convert_decimal_to_right(value, 4, 2)
# nb : -99.99

value = -1234.123
nb = convert_decimal_to_right(value, 4, 2, signed = False)
# nb : 0

value = 12.123
nb = convert_decimal_to_right(value, 8, 4)
# nb : 12.123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def trim_to_a_point(num, dec_point):
   
    factor = 10**dec_point # number of points to trim
    num = num*factor # multiple
    num = int(num) # use the trimming of int 
    num = num/factor #divide by the same factor of 10s you multiplied 
    
    return num


#test
a = 14.1234567
trim_to_a_point(a, 5)

output
========
14.12345
```

1. multiple by 10^ decimal point you want
2. truncate with int() method
3. divide by the same number you multiplied before
4. done!

Just posted this for educational reasons i think it is correct though :)