# Python round() unexpected results

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in

I was playing around with the Python round function when I noticed something weird. See for yourself:

CMD output:

```
1.5
2.5
0.5
2
2
0
```

Code:

```
a = 1.5 
b = 2.5
c = 0.5
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(round(a))
print(round(b))
print(round(c))
```

What's going on?

Comment: Only Mark Dickinson really understands how `round()` works ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/22155830/6260170

Comment: "if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice" — https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: Okay, so what *is* the weird thing you notice? Perhaps it's something else than we all seem to be assuming. (Use [edit] to add it into your question.)

Comment: though technically the _question_ is not a duplicate persay...  the answer from Mark Dickinson does answer this question when giving word of caution  in the other question

Comment: This is thoroughly addressed in the second answer on the duplicate question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22155830/146077

Answer (score -5):

```
a = 1.5 
b = 2.5
c = 0.5
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(round(a,0))
print(round(b,0))
print(round(c,0))
```

You can try it

Comment: This displays `2.0`, `2.0`, `0.0` on my Python 3. How exactly is that better? The added `.0`?

Comment: Sorry. 
You try this int(float(round(a,0))