# how to convert a float number to 4 decimal places without any rounding?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm going to take an integer number, then print root of that with `sqrt` function in float number to 4 decimal places without any rounding; but I have a problem. For example, when I take 3 as input, the output is 1.7320. It is correct; but when I take 4 as input, I expect 2.0000 as output; but what I see is 1.9999. What am I doing wrong?

```
import math
num = math.sqrt(float(input())) - 0.00005
print('%.4f' % num)
```

Comment: why is that surprising? sqrt of 4 is 2, and `2 - 0.00005` is `1.99995`...

Comment: Does [this answer to Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10826537/1115360) help?

Comment: if you run `print('%.16f' % num)` for example, you see that `num` is just a tiny bit smaller than 1.99995. `%.4f` consequently floors down to 1.9999. I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) is the right place to start reading further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your expected output for the square root of 3, it seems that you really just want to truncate or extend the square root output to 4 decimal places (rather than round up or down). If that is the case, you could just format to 5 decimal places and slice off the last character in the string (examples below replace your input with hardcoded strings for illustration).

```
import math

n = '{:.5f}'.format(math.sqrt(float('3')))[:-1]
print(n)
# 1.7320

n = '{:.5f}'.format(math.sqrt(float('4')))[:-1]
print(n)
# 2.0000
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Round float to x decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479163/round-float-to-x-decimals)

One of the solutions from that page would be to replace your print statement with: `print(format(num, '.4'))`

Using modern f-strings: `print(f'{num:.4f}')`