# Square roots by Newton’s method

Tags: scheme, precision, ieee-754

The following Scheme program implements [Newton’s method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) for computing the square root of a number:

```lisp
(import (scheme small))

(define (sqrt x)
  (define (sqrt-iter guess)
    (if (good-enough? guess)
      guess
      (sqrt-iter (improve guess))))
  (define (good-enough? guess)
    (define tolerance 0.001)
    (< (abs (- (square guess) x)) tolerance))
  (define (improve guess)
    (if (= guess 0) guess (average guess (/ x guess))))
  (define (average x y)
    (/ (+ x y) 2))
  (define initial-guess 1.0)
  (sqrt-iter initial-guess))

(display (sqrt 0)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e-12)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e-10)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e-8)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e-6)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e-4)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e-2)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e0)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e2)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e4)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e6)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e8)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e10)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e12)) (newline)
(display (sqrt 1e13))
```

Output:

> 0.03125
>   0.031250000010656254
>   0.03125000106562499
>   0.03125010656242753
>   0.031260655525445276
>   0.03230844833048122
>   0.10032578510960605
>   1.0
>   10.000000000139897
>   100.00000025490743
>   1000.0000000000118
>   10000.0
>   100000.0
>   1000000.0
>   [*Hanging forever…*]

As we can see, this naive program does not perform well:

- for *small* numbers (below `x` = 1e-2), the `tolerance` 0.001 is too large;
- for *large* numbers (from `x` = 1e13), the program hangs forever.

Both problems can be solved by redefining the `good-enough?` procedure like this:

```lisp
(define (good-enough? guess)
  (= (improve guess) guess))
```

But this solution is not the purpose of my post. Instead, I would like to understand why the naive program fails the way it fails for large numbers.

I have not read the [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://standards.ieee.org/content/ieee-standards/en/standard/754-2019.html) (IEEE 754), but to my understanding, floating-point numbers cannot represent all reals and have an *absolute precision* that is very high for small numbers and very low for large numbers (this [Wikipedia figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#/media/File:IEEE754.png) seems to confirm this). In other words, small floating-point numbers are dense and large floating-point numbers are sparse. The consequence of this, is that the naive program will hang forever, trapped in an infinite recursion, if `guess` has not reached the tolerance range yet and if `(improve guess)` cannot improve the `guess` anymore because the distance between the new `guess` and the old `guess` is below the absolute precision of the old `guess` (so the new `guess` is the same floating-point number as the old `guess`, meaning that a fixed point of `(improve guess)` has been reached).

To guarantee that, for a given `x`, the naive program returns, it seems to me that this predicate must hold:

> tolerance > absolute_precision(sqrt(`x`)).

If we choose a `tolerance` of 0.001 = 1e-3, that means that the absolute precision of sqrt(`x`) should be less than 1e-3. Consequently, according to the Wikipedia figure above for binary64 floating-point numbers, sqrt(`x`) should be less than 1e13 and therefore `x` should be less than 1e26.

Here are my questions:

1. Is my predicate correct?
2. Why does the program hang forever from `x` = 1e13 instead of the expected `x` = 1e26?
3. Why does the program hang forever with `x` in {1e13, 1e15, 1e17, …, 1e49} and any `x` greater than 1e49 but still return with `x` in {1e14, 1e16, 1e18, …, 1e48}?

*Note.* — I am using the [Chibi Scheme](http://synthcode.com/wiki/chibi-scheme) interpreter on a 64-bit MacBook Pro so the IEEE 754 binary64 format.

Comment: Tolerance needs to be relative, not absolute.

Answer (score 1):

When you square `3162277.6601683795` you get `10000000000000.002` (in binary this is infinite so looses precision compared to the argument). If you convert `10000000000000002` to hex you get `2386F26FC10002` which is 4x13 nibbles and `2` uses 2 bits. In float the msb is always 1 and is omitted so I'm guessing 53 bits is used and lots of decimals are skipped since that is how floating point works. You cannot get closer to `10000000000000` by tolerance `0.001` from either side

I'm thinking you could compare the guess with the previous guess and see if that is below a tolerance. eg.

```
(define (sqrt x)
  (define (sqrt-iter guess prev-guess)
    (if (good-enough? guess prev-guess)
      guess
      (sqrt-iter (improve guess) guess)))
  (define (good-enough? guess prev-guess)
    (define tolerance 1e-20)
    (< (abs (- guess prev-guess)) tolerance))
  (define (improve guess)
    (if (= guess 0) guess (average guess (/ x guess))))
  (define (average x y)
    (/ (+ x y) 2))
  (define initial-guess 1.0)
  (sqrt-iter initial-guess 0))
```

This results in `3162277.6601683795`. Unlike your version when you substract the guesses missing bits will make the difference smaller so even with a tolerance of `1e-20` it will produce an answer for `1e270`.

Now if you look at the guesses it makes it will jump quite large making the new guess always much better so only when the guess is close to the actual result it will be close to the previous guess and I'm guessing you would get as good estimate if your tolerance were just squared from the previous.

I agree that the fixed tolerance is no good and we should have had something that looks at the guesses divided with each other instead. When they are close the result will always be close to 1 and while it is off by much it will be close to 2 or 1/2 depending. Just comparing without tolerance might put you in a an infinite loop when the `improve` will jump over and under the mark and never match so the tolerance was put in there for a reason.

Comment: If I understood correctly you are advocating this redefinition of the `good-enough?` procedure: `(define (good-enough? guess) (< (abs (- (improve guess) guess)) tolerance)))`. As I said, finding the correct implementation was not the purpose of my post, but this is still an interesting discussion. So which implementation do you think is better: yours or mine: `(define (good-enough? guess) (= (improve guess) guess))`? In [this wiki](http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-1.7), Owen suggests that it is mine (actually his) because without tolerance we get the best square root approximation.

Comment: @Maggyero No. More like `(define (good-enough? guess previous-guess) (< (abs (-  previous-guess guess)) tolerance)))`. `improve` also uses `x`, which is wrong. If you really want `previous-guess` as a free variable you need to define the helpers inside `sqrt-iter` instead of `sqrt`

Comment: This is very interesting but to be sure that I follow you, could you write your corrected version of my *whole* program in your answer?

Comment: @Maggyero It's been a long time since I did this and I went back to [the wizards](https://youtu.be/-J_xL4IGhJA?t=3439) and it seems your implementation is correct except for the `0` case in `improve` which will break `sqrt` for small numbers.  I'll have another look at this today and see if I can answer why it loops endlessly. Which implementation are you using? Last time I did this was in my [Extended Brainfuck Compiler](https://github.com/westerp/ebf-compiler/blob/ba9833f938da4a37c33defbadfd74502d2bc2397/ebf.ebf#L460)

Comment: I am using the Chibi Scheme interpreter. You said "`improve` also uses x, which is wrong." How would you implement the `improve` procedure?

Comment: "Just comparing without tolerance might put you in a an infinite loop when the `improve` will jump over and under the mark and never match so the tolerance was put in there for a reason." Do you mean for this definition: `(define (good-enough? guess) (= (improve guess) guess))`? Yet in [this wiki](http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-1.7) Owen says: "I believe is the best solution, guaranteeing to stop and at the same time, with the best accuracy." And I confirm that I could not make it fail. Are you sure it can fail? If so could you provide a value for x that make it fail?