# How to roundup and round down the decimal part in python

Tags: python

how to round down and round up the decimal vlaues in pytho.

user input

```
      a =2.336  After round up it should be like a =2.34
      a =4.13623  After round up it should be like a =4.14
```

Is there any built in functions in python to manipulate

Comment: Maybe you're just looking for `round(a, 2)` to round to 2 digits? Your question is not quite clear, are you looking for ceil/floor to a given precision, or just the general round operation to a give precision?

Comment: If you're just looking for rounding, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/13479163/3216427 Otherwise the answer below are good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round float to x decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479163/round-float-to-x-decimals)

Answer (score 2):

you could try something like

```
a = 2.336
a = math.ceil(a*pow(10,2))/pow(10,2)
```

here `2` in `pow(10,2)` stands for the precision you need behind the decimal point

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **`ceil()`** and **`floor()`** functions from the *math* module. Here's some code to help you get started.

```
def round_up(n, decimals=0):
   multiplier = 10 ** decimals
   return math.ceil(n * multiplier) / multiplier
```

Try figuring out how the decimal and multiplier variables are working here.