# How to round number to 3 decimals max?

Tags: python, numbers

I am trying to round up 5.9999998 to 5.999.

But I have a problem, If I do round(number) it'll round it up to 6. How can I round a number like this to max 3 decimals?

Comment: Read (study) both answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479163/round-float-to-x-decimals

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round float to x decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479163/round-float-to-x-decimals)

Comment: that isn't rounding, that is *truncating*

Comment: Are you trying to _round_, _round up_ or _truncate_? You mention all three options and it is not clear what you're asking. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean, and use the correct words (round/ceil/floor/truncate) to make this question searchable and useful for future readers.

Comment: Note that due to ambiguity of the question, there are now different answers with different results...

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
number = 5.999999998
new_number = int(number * 1e3) / 1e3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short code.

```py
x = 4/3

# round up to 3 decimal places
x = round(x, 3)

print(x)
```

Comment: This is not quite what he wants, he doesn't want to round , but to truncate
I think he is confusing the two terms

Comment: Do you mean not round off the last digit but taking only the 3 digits after the decimal point?

Comment: Nope, that's what I meant. Thanks, it works.

Comment: Really ? When you execute this code with your number : 5.9999998  it returns 6.0, not 5.999, then I think your example was wrong