# Python 3 Decimal rounding half down with ROUND_HALF_UP context

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, rounding

Can anybody explain or propose a fix for why when I round a decimal in Python 3 with the context set to round half up, it rounds 2.5 to 2, whereas in Python 2 it rounds correctly to 3:

Python 3.4.3 and 3.5.2:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> context = decimal.getcontext()
>>> context.rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> round(decimal.Decimal('2.5'))
2
>>> decimal.Decimal('2.5').__round__()
2
>>> decimal.Decimal('2.5').quantize(decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('3')
```

Python 2.7.6:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> context = decimal.getcontext()
>>> context.rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> round(decimal.Decimal('2.5'))
3.0
>>> decimal.Decimal('2.5').quantize(decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('3')
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Notice that when you call `round` you are getting a float value as a result, not a `Decimal`. `round` is coercing the value to a float and then rounding that according to the rules for rounding a float.

If you use the optional `ndigits` parameter when you call `round()` you will get back a Decimal result and in this case it will round the way you expected.

```
Python 3.4.1 (default, Sep 24 2015, 20:41:10) 
[GCC 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import decimal
>>> context = decimal.getcontext()
>>> context.rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
>>> round(decimal.Decimal('2.5'), 0)
Decimal('3')
```

I haven't found where it is documented that `round(someDecimal)` returns an int but `round(someDecimal, ndigits)` returns a decimal, but that seems to be what happens in Python 3.3 and later. In Python 2.7 you always get a float back when you call `round()` but Python 3.3 improved the integration of `Decimal` with the Python builtins.

As noted in a comment, `round()` delegates to `Decimal.__round__()` and that indeed shows the same behaviour:

```
>>> Decimal('2.5').__round__()
2
>>> Decimal('2.5').__round__(0)
Decimal('3')
```

I note that the documentation for `Fraction` says:

```
__round__()
__round__(ndigits)
The first version returns the nearest int to self, rounding half to even.
The second version rounds self to the nearest multiple of Fraction(1, 10**ndigits)
(logically, if ndigits is negative), again rounding half toward even. 
This method can also be accessed through the round() function.
```

Thus the behaviour is consistent in that with no argument it changes the type of the result and rounds half to even, however it seems that `Decimal` fails to document the behaviour of its `__round__` method.

Edit to note as Barry Hurley says in the comments, `round()` is documented as returning a `int` if called without the optional arguments and a "floating point value" if given the optional argument. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: Thanks @Duncan for the explanation, it is always good to try understand these things. It seems very odd that a different _type_ is returned depending on whether you specify ndigits or not.

Comment: As an add-on, python 3 docs state that it delegates to `number.__round__(ndigits)` and the `decimal` module implements has it's own `__round__` method

Comment: @Dunca, it looks to be an int, rather than float though: "If ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns the nearest integer to its input." https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: @BarryHurley right you are, so that's the documentation link that I didn't spot (though 'floating point value' isn't perhaps the best way to express it). I've updated my answer to include this.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @Duncan's answer, the `round` builtin function changed between python 2 and python 3 to round to the nearest even number (which is the norm in statistics).

Python2 docs:

> ...if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done away
>   from 0 (so, for example, round(0.5) is 1.0 and round(-0.5) is -1.0).

Python3 docs:

> ...if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even
>   choice (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and
>   round(1.5) is 2)

Since `round` converts to `float` if no argument is given for `ndigits` (credit to @Duncan's answer), `round` behaves the same way as it would for `float`s.

Examples (in python3):

```
>>> round(2.5)
2
>>> round(2.500000001)
3
>>> round(3.5)
4
```

Comment: Thanks @Billy, but both round(1.5) and round(2.5) give 2 in Python 3, which I presume is due to how those 1.5 and 2.5 floats are represented internally. round in Python 2 returns floats for these, versus ints int Python 3.

Comment: It has nothing to do with internal representations.  Python's floating point implementation can represent 1.5 and 2.5 *precisely* (i.e. no floating-point rounding errors like you would get with the number 1.1).  Since 1.5 is *exactly* equal in distance from 1 and 2, python 3 rounds to the nearest even number, which is 2.  Similarly, 2.5 is *exactly* between 2 and 3, so it is rounded to the nearest even number, which is again 2.

Answer (score 4):

This is a combination of changes between the rounding mode of `round` in Python 2 vs 3 and the re-implementation of `Decimal` from Python to `C` (See *"Other final large-scale changes"* in the [Features for 3.3 section PEP 398](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0398/#features-for-3-3)).

For `round`, the rounding strategy changed as can be seen in [What's New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html) [Also see [Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior) ]. Additionally, `round` in Python `3` first tries to [find an appropriate `__round__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee1e01ceb00e29487c229246bbae0c63da135cb3/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2037) method defined for the object passed:

```
>>> round('1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method
```

While in Python `2.x` it first tries to [coerce it specifically to a `float`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2182) and then round it:

```
>>> round('1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
```

For `Decimal`, in Python `2`, the implementation even lacked a `__round__` method to be called:

```
>>> Decimal.__round__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Decimal' has no attribute '__round__'
```

So, calling `round` on a `Decimal` object coerced it to a `float` which  got [rounded using `_Py_double_round`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#l2215); this resulted in a `float` always getting returned irregardless of if a value for `ndigits` was supplied. `decimal` is implemented in pure Python for `2.x` and (was?) for Python `3` until `3.2`.

[In Python `3.3` it got shinny new `__round__` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1d0d35423dd0c13cd8306f3351e86873e6af5c5f/Modules/_decimal/_decimal.c#L3614) as it was re-implemented in `C`:

```
>>> Decimal.__round__
<method '__round__' of 'decimal.Decimal' objects>
```

and now, it gets picked up by `round` when `round(<Decimal_object>)` is invoked.

This, mapped to `PyDec_Round` in `C`, now [returns a PyLong](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1d0d35423dd0c13cd8306f3351e86873e6af5c5f/Modules/_decimal/_decimal.c#L3657) (an integer) using the default context (`ROUND_HALF_EVEN`) if the argument `ndigits` is not supplied and, if it is, calls [`quantize`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1d0d35423dd0c13cd8306f3351e86873e6af5c5f/Modules/_decimal/_decimal.c#L3648) on it and returns a new rounded `Decimal` object.

Answer (score 1):

German and Swiss laws require you to round up VAT from 0.005 to 0.01 *("kaufmännisches Runden")*. I played around with `Decimal` and this what I ended up with:

```
from decimal import *

class Number(object):
    '''generic class for rounding:
        Banking:     ROUND_HALF_EVEN  # default
        Germany:     ROUND_HALF_UP    # for VAT
        Switzerland: ROUND_DOWN       # for some taxes
                     ROUND_HALF_UP    # for some taxes like VAT
    '''
    def __init__(self, digits=2, rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP):
        getcontext().rounding=rounding        
        self.base = Decimal(10) ** -digits
        
    def round(self, value, digits=None):
        if digits:
            base = Decimal(10) ** - digits
        else:
            base = self.base
        return float(Decimal(str(value)).quantize(base))
```

Example:

```
>>> a = Number()
>>> a.round(1301.685)
1301.69
```