# function round() doesn't work as I expect

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I am trying to use round function here. Sometimes it round down from `.5` sometimes round up. So what's the problem?

Source file:

```
print("rounding up 0.5 is",round(.5))
print("rounding up 1.5 is",round(1.5))
print("rounding up 2.5 is",round(2.5))
print("rounding up 3.5 is",round(3.5))
```

Output:

```
rounding up 0.5 is 0
rounding up 1.5 is 2
rounding up 2.5 is 2
rounding up 3.5 is 4
```

Comment: This is python3 I suppose? Because it works fine for python2

Comment: Round-.5-to-even-digit is standard in many fields of math, especially statistics, so it's often the standard in many programming languages as well.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

> if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice

So when you say `rounding up`, it's not necessarily rounding up. It's just rounding.

Comment: *"It's just rounding"* This specific technique (rounding to even integers when at *.5) is called ["banker's rounding"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)