# Why does round(5/2) return 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

Using python 3.4.3,

```
round(5/2) # 2
```

Shouldn't it return 3?

I tried using python 2 and it gave me the correct result

```
round(5.0/2) # 3
```

How can I achieve a correct rounding of floats?

Comment: This is documented behavior in python. It differs between Python3 and Python2.

Comment: Since `5` and `2` are both integers, `5/2` is also an integer in Python 2.x, but in Python 3.x it should give you what you expect. I suspect you got the Python 2/3 backwards.

Comment: This is often called [Bankers' Rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python 3.x rounding behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior)

Comment: Thanks for the reference, @Phylogenesis!  I didn't know this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even
>   choice (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and
>   round(1.5) is 2).

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) for the `round` function.
Hope this helps :)

On a side note, I would suggest always read the doc when you face this kind of question ([haha](https://xkcd.com/293/))

Answer (score 5):

Rounding toward even is correct behavior for Python 3.  According to the Python 3 [documentation for `round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

> ...if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and round(1.5) is 2)

Since 2.5 is equally close to 2 and 3, it rounds down to 2.

In Python 2, the [docs for `round()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#round) state:

> ...if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done away from 0 (so, for example, round(0.5) is 1.0 and round(-0.5) is -1.0)

Since 2.5 is equally close to 2 and 3, it rounds up to 3 (away from zero).

If you want to control how numbers round, the best way to do it might be the way I learned to round numbers back in my Applesoft BASIC days:

```
10 X = 5
15 PRINT "ROUND(" X "/2) = " (INT((X/2)+0.5))
20 X = 4.99
25 PRINT "ROUND(" X "/2) = " (INT((X/2)+0.5))
```

Umm...make that:

```
>>> x = 5 / 2
>>> print(x)
2.5
>>> y = int(x + 0.5)
>>> print(y)
3
>>> x = 4.99 / 2
>>> print(x)
2.495
>>> y = int(x + 0.5)
>>> print(y)
2
>>>
```

Comment: Many old BASIC dialects I know round down on `INT()`, including negative numbers. I don't know Applesoft BASIC, but if http://www.calormen.com/jsbasic/ is accurate, it does, too. So Python `int(x + 0.5)` is only equivalent to many olden days BASIC `INT(X + 0.5)` for positive numbers. In Python you could use `math.floor(x + 0.5)`.

Answer (score 0):

From [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)

> round(number[, ndigits]) -> number Round a number to a given
>   precision in decimal digits (default 0 digits).This returns an int
>   when called with one argument, otherwise the same type as the number.
>   ndigits may be negative.

So

```
>>>round(5/2)
2
>>>round(5.0/2, 1)
2.5
```