# Very Strange Rounding of Numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

You might consider this question as a duplicate of [Python Rounding Inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258464/python-rounding-inconsistently).

However I still think that there is a justification to emphasise this Python behaviour with it.

---

While using Python to prepare test data for a C program, I have found this strange behaviour of Python. The rounding of 'halves' come out in pairs!

Can anybody please provide an explanation?

Positive:

```
>>> round (0.5)
0
>>> round (1.5)
2
>>> round (2.5)
2
>>> round (3.5)
4
>>> round (4.5)
4
>>> round (5.5)
6
>>> round (6.5)
6
```

Negative:

```
>>> round(-0.5)
0
>>> round(-1.5)
-2
>>> round(-2.5)
-2
>>> round(-3.5)
-4
>>> round(-4.5)
-4
>>> round(-5.5)
-6
>>> round(-6.5)
-6
>>> round(-7.5)
-8
>>> round(-8.5)
-8
```

Comment: The current dup target is not correct, but the question is still a duplicate. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior).

Comment: ok that's sounds better. I still think that there is room for titling it as a strange behaviour so that programmers will take attention

Comment: Yep, that's the reason of marking duplicates - people can find them and they serve as sign posts to a single canonical answer. (Duplicate does not mean the question is bad. On the contrary, it may help others who look for the same terms.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common rounding method, called ***Banker’s Rounding***: if a number is right in the middle, it rounds to the next *even* number, not *down*, as the standard rounding does.

This is useful to reduce accumulation of rounding errors; with *Banker’s Rounding*, the errors have a better chance to even out over many transactions, instead of accumulating continuously.

Comment: Thank you the answer! I find it very annoying that a programming language takes such a high-level decision within its core functionality. I'm actually quite socked by that!