# Why does Python round(x, 0) not equal round(x)?

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of rounding decimal values. The code below is supposed to illustrate the difference in rounding the decimal value 1.5 according to both the half up and half down methods. See comments in the code for specific questions, which revolve around the difference in behaviour in rounding to zero decimal places versus the nearest integer. I would have expected no difference, i.e. these two cases to be equivalent, but looks like not:

```
import decimal

a: decimal.Decimal = decimal.Decimal('1.5')

decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN
print(f'{decimal.getcontext()=}')
print(f'{a=}, {round(a, 0)=}') # This rounds down as expected
print(f'{a=}, {round(a)=}') # This rounds up, why? And why does round not appear to return a decimal here?

decimal.getcontext().rounding = decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP
print(f'{decimal.getcontext()=}')
print(f'{a=}, {round(a, 0)=}') # This rounds up as expected
print(f'{a=}, {round(a)=}') # This rounds up as expected, but again does not return a decimal
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Rounding Inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258464/python-rounding-inconsistently)

Comment: See this issue: [Document the behaviour of `Decimal.__round__` #101575](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/101575)

Comment: @MarcoF.: No, it does not answer this question. That question is about differences in `round(x)` for different values of `x`. This question is about differences in `round(x)` and `round(x, 0)` for the same value of `x`.

Comment: At the very least, they are not equivalent if only for the fact that `round(a)` always returns a value of type `int`, while `round(a, 0)` returns a value of type `type(a)`. (See `help(round)`.) This is, of course, not sufficient to explain why the rounding behavior is different for non-`int` `a` values.