# Python int() to the nearest value

Tags: python, int

The way the python `int()`function works rounds a number to the smallest value.

Such that `4.99 = 4`

What can I do if I want 4.99 be equal to 5?

Comment: If you can deal with bankers rounding, using [`round`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior)

Comment: Google "python round to nearest integer". Did you do any research before posting? The answer is *trivially* easy to find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int()` *truncates* float values, removing the non-integral portion of the number. You are looking for *rounding* instead.

You can use the [`round()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) for that:

```
>>> round(4.99)
5
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) builtin:

```
>>> round(4.99)
5
```

Answer (score 0):

[`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil) and [`math.floor`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.floor) return floats which are the nearest whole numbers above or below the parameter.