# Pythonic way to "round()" like Javascript "Math.round()"?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, math

I want the most Pythonic way to round numbers just like Javascript does (through `Math.round()`). They're actually slightly different, but this difference can make huge difference for my application.

**Using `round()` method from Python 3:**

```
// Returns the value 20
x = round(20.49)

// Returns the value 20
x = round(20.5)

// Returns the value -20
x = round(-20.5)

// Returns the value -21
x = round(-20.51)
```

**Using `Math.round()` method from Javascript*:**

```
// Returns the value 20
x = Math.round(20.49);

// Returns the value 21
x = Math.round(20.5);

// Returns the value -20
x = Math.round(-20.5);

// Returns the value -21
x = Math.round(-20.51);
```

Thank you!

**References:**

- [Math.round() explanation at Mozilla Developers Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: Please specify which version of python you are using, as this may be different between python 2 and python 3.

Comment: First of all, why the negative point without any explanation about that? And thank you @khelwood, I'll provide the information.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10825926/3005167) and its answers might shade light on the situation.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the Python version!

Comment: Thank you for the linked question, @kazemakase . Now I understand why Python3 choose to round numbers this way.

Comment: FWIW, asking a question that implies that Python is inferior in some way to JavaScript may not be well-received by many Pythonistas. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Seems to you that I'm arguing that? I'm moving a Javascript code to Python, I NEED THE EXACT behavior in both cases, why this implies that Python is worst than JS? The project involves the measurement of metrics like temperature and pressure, I can't change the way we normalize / convert the data to the correct value. It's simple as that.

Comment: @FernandoPaladini: That makes perfect sense. My comment wasn't serious, hence the smilie. Still, plenty of Pythonistas are not big fans of JavaScript...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
import math
def roundthemnumbers(value):
    x = math.floor(value)
    if (value - x) < .50:
        return x
    else:
        return math.ceil(value)
```

Haven't had my coffee yet, but that function should do what you need.  Maybe with some minor revisions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer too, @JessePardue . I haven't named your question as the best one because your solution is slightly more complex than the other. Anyway, thank you for the answer!

Comment: Just two questions: (a) Why are you returning the values inside a parenthesis? (b) Why you store `y` before returning it? Isn't better return the value directly?

Comment: @FernandoPaladini: In Python, `math.ceil(value)` creates a float object with the required value, doing `y = math.ceil(value)` merely binds that object to the name `y` (which is a fairly efficient operation); it doesn't create a copy of the value, so it's not as inefficient as it might first appear (or as it would be in most other languages).

Comment: Alright, the corrections have been made and the function name--as you can see--has been made intuitive, lol.

Comment: I think you want `< 0.5` instead of `<= 0.5`: the exact halfway cases should round up instead of down.

Comment: Yes, @MarkDickinson is right about the comment above. Should be `< 0.5` instead of `<= 0.5`.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that under usual IEEE 754 rules (i.e., round-ties-to-even rounding mode), this function gives the correct result for all inputs, though that's not completely obvious from the implementation. The potential problem is that `value - x` may not be exactly representable, and the rounding step implicit in that subtraction could potentially alter the comparison result. However, a closer analysis shows that `value - x` *is* exactly representable for `x` not in `(-0.5, 0)`, and for values in `(-0.5, 0)` we always have `value - x >= 0.5`, even after taking rounding into account.

Comment: Actually, ignore the bit about the rounding mode; this should work for any of the four standard IEEE 754 rounding modes. The key observation is that in the troublesome interval, the exact value of `value - x` is strictly greater than `0.5`, and it follows that the rounded value of `value - x` is greater than or equal to `0.5`, no matter what the rounding mode. So `value` will always end up being rounded up, as it should be.

Answer (score 7):

The behavior of Python's `round` function changed between Python 2 and Python 3.  But it looks like you want the following, which will work in either version:

```
math.floor(x + 0.5)
```

This should produce the behavior you want.

Comment: Note that there are some edge case inputs that aren't properly handled by this solution: examples are `0.49999999999999994` (which produces `1.0` instead of `0.0`), `5000000000000001.0` (which produces `5000000000000002.0`), `-0.3` (which produces `0.0` instead of `-0.0`). If you care about those edge cases, something along the lines of @JessePardue's solution is better.

Comment: Wooow, thanks for the advise, @MarkDickinson . Yes, the first and the second situation are very important to me, I really care about that. I'll change my solution to the one pointed by JessePardue. Again, thank you for the advise!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using round() function in python you can use the floor function and ceil function in python to accomplish your task.

floor(x+0.5)

or

ceil(x-0.5)