# Pandas code to round values greater than 0.5 to 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having a dataframe column and want to round it. If the value is equal to 0.5  it is getting rounded as 0, but i want it to be 1 if the value is greater than or equal to 0.5. 
Could someone please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round float 0.5 up to 1.0, while still rounding 0.45 to 0.0, as the usual school rounding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851273/how-to-round-float-0-5-up-to-1-0-while-still-rounding-0-45-to-0-0-as-the-usual)

Comment: have you tried `df.round(0)`?

Comment: @mad_ yes but rounding to zero

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned by @ALoolz in a comment, pandas (and python in general) is using  a rounding to minimize bias when summing different elements, called [Rounding half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_half_to_even).

As Wikipedi says:

> **Rounding half to even**
>
> A tie-breaking rule without positive/negative
> bias and without bias toward/away from zero is round half to even. By
> this convention, if the fractional part of `x` is `0.5`, then `y` is the
> even integer nearest to `x`. Thus, for example, `+23.5` becomes `+24`, as
> does `+24.5`; however, `−23.5` becomes `−24`, as does `−24.5`. This function
> minimizes the expected error when summing over rounded figures, even
> when the inputs are mostly positive or mostly negative, provided they
> are neither mostly even nor mostly odd.
>
> This variant of the round-to-nearest method is also called convergent
> rounding, statistician's rounding, Dutch rounding, Gaussian rounding,
> odd–even rounding,[6] or bankers' rounding.
>
> This is the default rounding mode used in IEEE 754 operations for
> results in binary floating-point formats, and the more sophisticated
> mode[clarification needed] used when rounding to significant figures.
>
> By eliminating bias, repeated addition or subtraction of independent
> numbers, as in a one-dimensional random walk, will give a rounded
> result with an error that tends to grow in proportion to the square
> root of the number of operations rather than linearly.
>
> However, this rule distorts the distribution by increasing the
> probability of evens relative to odds. Typically this is less
> important[citation needed] than the biases that are eliminated by this
> method.

In your case, if you want to use the rounding used "in school" called [Rounding half up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_half_up), you could apply a function that adds 0.5 and then truncate: `lambda x: int(x + 0.5)`

So, you should do when rounding your DataFrame:

```py
df_rounding_half_up = df.applymap(lambda x: int(x + 0.5))
```

... while Python-default round up to even would be something like:

```py
df_rounding_half_to_even = df.applymap(lambda x: int(round(x, 0)))
```

Answer (score -2):

There seems to be an issue in `pandas.round` function which does not round `0.5` to `1`. In that case you could use built-in `round` with `applymap`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def getRound(x):
    return(round(x))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([3, 3]),
columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['first', 'second', 'third'])
```

`df` will look like this

```
               A         B         C
first   0.474011  0.082135  0.476545
second  0.313154  0.265458  0.523410
third   0.057491  0.141635  0.037582
```

Change one value to be `0.5`

```
df['A'][1]=0.5
```

Apply lambda function

```
df.applymap(getRound)
```

Output:

```
          A    B    C
first   0.0  0.0  0.0
second  1.0  0.0  1.0
third   0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an `issue`. It's a conscious decision to have an unbiased method of rounding, see [Round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even)

Comment: Correct link to the article is now:
[Rounding half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_half_to_even)