# How to Roundoff 0.5 to nearest integer in python?

Tags: python, pandas, math, decimal, rounding

My input looks like below:

```
Name Sep     Oct
Amy  833.33  833.33
Eve  20774.5  0
```

My Expected Output is:

```
Name Sep     Oct
Amy  833     833
Eve  20775   0
```

When I apply np.ceil to round 0.5 to nearest integer, my output becomes:

```
Name Sep     Oct
Amy  834     834
Eve  20775   0
```

How to apply `np.ceil` only to values having decimal greater than or equal to 0.5? Or is there any other way to get my desired output.

Comment: What about `np.round`?

Comment: Or simply `round()` https://docs.python.org/fr/3.7/library/functions.html#round

Comment: Or https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#round for those of us limited to English.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `np.round` and cast to `int`  .

like this:

```
int(np.round(833.33))
```

Output:

`833`

Answer (score 1):

[**`np.ceil()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html) always rounds up while [**`np.floor()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html) always rounds down.

[**`np.round()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.round.html) is close but does not always round up for *.5. As [@Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom) suggested, it turns out this rounding inconsistency is [by design](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) (emphasis added):

> `numpy.around(a, decimals=0, out=None)`
>
> ***Evenly*** round to the given number of decimals.

So for example 20774.5 rounds down to 20774 while 20775.5 rounds up to 20776.

There are some workarounds in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43851273/13138364). Here's one way to [**`applymap()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) one of those workarounds:

```py
df[['Sep', 'Oct']] = df[['Sep', 'Oct']].applymap(
    lambda x: np.ceil(x) if float(x) % 1 >= 0.5 else np.round(x))

#   Name      Sep    Oct
# 0  Amy    833.0  833.0
# 1  Eve  20775.0    0.0
```

Comment: I have tried the above, but my number remains at 20774.0 instead of 20775

Comment: I think that's just one of the occasional artifacts of floating point precision. See: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @tdy it could also be round to even mode.  It's hard to tell without printing the number to at least 17 digits.

Comment: @MarkRansom good point, that's indeed the case. updated to reflect this

Comment: @Akshayashiva it turns out this rounding inconsistency is actually due to "banker rounding" and is by design (not just a floating point artifact). i updated the answer to show a workaround for restoring "school rounding"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my output by applying the following query:

```
df['Sep'][(df['Sep']%1) >= 0.5] = df['Sep'].apply(np.ceil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inpt_strg = '''

Name Sep Oct
Amy 833.33 833.33
Eve 20774.5 0

'''
s_lst = inpt_strg.splitlines()
n_lst = [list(str.split(" ")) for str in s_lst]

def fl(i):
 try: return float (i)
 except ValueError: return i

def rd(i):
  if isinstance(i, float):
    if (abs(i)%1)*10>=5:return int (i) + 1
    else: return int (i)
  else: return i

r_lst = [[rd(fl(i)) for i in sub] for sub in n_lst]

from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(r_lst,tablefmt='plain'))
```

Output:-

```
Name  Sep    Oct
Amy   833    833
Eve   20775  0
```