# Python list vector matrix decimals 0s 1s

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, vector

I have a list in python

```
l=[[0.1,0.2,0.9],[0.3,0.4,0.6],[0.8,0.2,0.8]]
```

if `element <=0.5`, return `0`, 
if `element > 0.5`, return `1`

Hence resulting l should look like:

```
l=[[0,0,1],[0,0,1],[1,0,1]]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question? This is not a code-writing service. It is a question and answer site.

Comment: Take a look at [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

Comment: Why is 0.5 being rounded down?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#round).

```
>>> l=[[0.1,0.2,0.9],[0.3,0.4,0.6],[0.8,0.2,0.8]]
>>> [[round(x) for x in i] for i in l]
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

As mentioned by @iAdjunct in the comments and discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10825926/3044673) question, if working on python 2 this will *not* result in desired output.

That is because they adopt different rounding methods. The difference can be illustrate with these examples:

Python2:

```
>>> round(0.5)
1.0
```

Python3

```
>>> round(0.5)
0
```

Comment: Note: his function is actually not the same as round because, for some reason, he's rounding 0.5 *down* instead of *up*

Comment: Just tested in python3.6 and `round(0.5)` returns `0`.

Comment: `Python 2.7.10` returns `1.0`. That is weird; Python2's `round` function is consistent with the traditional definition of round, but Python3's implements the round-half-to-even paradigm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can do this; either in pure Python via list comprehension or in a vectorised fashion using a 3rd party library.

**Pure Python**

You can use a nested list comprehension.

```
l = [[0.1,0.2,0.9],[0.3,0.4,0.6],[0.8,0.2,0.8]]

res = [[0 if i <= 0.5 else 1 for i in row] for row in l]

[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
```

**Vectorised alternative**

This uses the 3rd party library `numpy`.

```
import numpy as np

res = np.where(np.array(l) <= 0.5, 0, 1)

array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]])
```

**Note on rounding**

Comparing floats with floats is difficult due to the nature of `float` *not* storing numeric data in base-10 format. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) for more details. This is a problem even with the above methods.

This means you may have to take particular care for boundary cases, if this matters to you.