# Rounding numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=0.005
print ('%.2f'%a)
b=90.005
print('%.2f'%b)
c=90.015
print('%.2f'%c)
```

Above code is written in python3 and the output is following:

```
 0.01
 90.00
 90.02
```

Is this any kind of computational error or m missing a point?

Comment: @mhd That doesn't explain why the first and last are rounded

Comment: If I'd to guess, it's somewhat related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: I think this explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior)

Comment: @thesilkworm that question answers my problem properly. Looking for a better answer

Comment: What's your question? When you round a number to 2 digits, if the 3rd digit is 0-4 it is rounded down while if the 3rd digit is 5-9 it is rounded up. Your example is exactly what is expected when rounding numbers. Are you trying to do something different?

Comment: @divisbisan I think u hadn't observed my question properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is the second one, which is

```
b = 90.005
print('%.2f' % b)
```

Now as @divibisan said, if the digit is between 0-4, it's rounded down, if it's between 5-9, it's rounded up. So why is `90.005` not rounded up ?

Because computers can not represent the floating points precisely. If you look at it closely you will see that `90.005` is represented as,

```
>>> print('%.50f' % b)
90.00499999999999545252649113535881042480468750000000
```

That's the reason it is being rounded down, while others behave normally.

```
>>> print ('%.50f'%a)
0.00500000000000000010408340855860842566471546888351
# 0.01

>>> print ('%.50f'%c)
90.01500000000000056843418860808014869689941406250000
# 90.02
```

Comment: Yupp, i understand this, So whats the possible solution for this, I face this problem several times at HakerRank

Comment: You need to convert them to integers, do calculations and after that convert to floating points.

Comment: OK, means there is no efficient solution for it.

Comment: @ShivendraSaxena From the documentation: **For use cases which require exact decimal representation, try using the decimal module which implements decimal arithmetic suitable for accounting applications and high-precision applications.**

Comment: Can u provide me reference link of that doc

Comment: @Shivendra Saxena https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html