# Why the round() function in python giving different result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take the round of float number but in python for different  float values it gives the different result. Example : -

```
>>> round(4.5)
4
```

and

```
>>> round(3.5)
4
```

as you can see the result `round(4.5)` return `4` while `rount(3.5)` return `4`. How to solve this problem. ? I want `round(4.5)` to return `5`. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior)

Answer (score 2):

See [official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round).

Basically it called even round. It will round `x.5` value into even choice.

And here is [why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

Comment: Banker's rounding, no?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Indeed, that's another name for it. It's also the default for IEEE 754, so Python is being nice and compliant here. :P

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

> if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and round(1.5) is 2).

I.e. Python 3 does ["rounding half to even"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

You can do "round up" this way:

```
import math
def round_up(x):
    return math.floor(x + 0.5)
```