# Wrong result on rounding method with 2 decimal places

Tags: python, rounding

I got confusing with the result of round() with 2 decimal places

```
a = 1352.845
res = round(a, 2)
=> 1352.85 (Right as I expected)

b = 578.005
res = round(b, 2)
=> 578.0 (Wrong, It would be 578.01 instead of 578.0)
```

what happens with case b or Have I misunderstood anything?

**Answer**:

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_UP

Decimal('578.005').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_UP)
```

Because it needs to be used for monetary so the default convention of python round() (Banker's Rounding) doesn't right in my case

Answer (score 2):

While it can be confusing, this is due to the fact that most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as a `float` type.

For further reference, see: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues

Answer (score 2):

It is not wrong actually.
It is [Banker's Rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior) and is an implementation detail on purpose.

If you wish to retain the 'always round 0.5 up' method, you can do so by doing:

```
import decimal
#The rounding you are looking for
decimal.Decimal('3.5').quantize(decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
>>> Decimal('4')
decimal.Decimal('2.5').quantize(decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
>>> Decimal('3')


#Other kinds of rounding
decimal.Decimal('2.5').quantize(decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN)
>>> Decimal('2')

decimal.Decimal('3.5').quantize(decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN)
>>> Decimal('3')
```

Comment: Banker's rounding (a.k.a. "round ties to even") isn't relevant here, because the values that the OP is rounding are _not_ ties. Note that `1352.845` is rounding _up_, not down as you might expect from Banker's Rounding. That's because the actual value stored here is `1352.845000000000027284841053187847137451171875`; that value is fractionally closer to 1352.85 than to 1352.84, so it rounds up.

Answer (score 0):

Recall your Physics / Mathematics lesson where they taught how rounding off works.

If the last digit is a '5' and you round that off, it's preceding digit shall move to the next even digit if it is odd but shall remain the same if it is already even.

Comment: That's not true. What you are describing is Bankers' Rounding and is by no means the standard for many use cases

Comment: Well, that is considered to be the standard in many countries (India included) when it comes to scientific calculations. Also, Python's `round` function seem to be following this convention.