# Tie breaking of rint in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

A very similar question was asked 8 years ago in this post [Tie breaking of round with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000574/tie-breaking-of-round-with-numpy). But the chosen answer at that time doesn't actually really answer the question: the question was asking about how to customize the tiebreaker, while the answer given was actually customizing the entire behavior of rounding.

For example: both `rint(1.5)` and `rint(2.5)` will return 2 because of IEEE 754 convention, but I (and probably the original PO) want to tweak the tie-breaker such that on tie it rounds to zero i.e. `rint(1.5) = 1`, `rint(2.5) = 2`, `rint(-1.5) = -1`.

But following the solution in the above mentioned post and setting rounding mode to `FE_TOWARDZERO` with `ctype` will cause `rint(1.6) = 1` which is not desired as it changes the entire rounding behavior of `rint` from round to the closet integer to round towards zero.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have that level of control within `rint`.  You can have the default (banker's rounding) or the draconian choices afforded by the [C rounding modes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round).

Python's `Decimal` package can give you [finer control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809196/wrong-result-on-rounding-method-with-2-decimal-places).

Comment: Decimal package can do that for a single value but doesn't work very elegantly with numpy arrays. C rounding modes is not the feature I'm looking for. I want to keep it as round to the nearest int except different tiebreaker.