# Pandas Rounding Columns for Exact Value

Tags: python, pandas

My input dataframe;

```
     A          B       C 
0    0          1       1.3
1    1.2        2       2.25
2    1.5        3       4.42
3    2.7        4       5.12
4    3.9        5       6.24
5    4.55       6       7.25
```

I want to round the C columns according to a threshold in dataframe. But i couldn' t get the desired results.

Code is;

```
threshold=0.25
df['C']=round(df['C'] - threshold+0.5)
```

Output is;

```
     A          B       C 
0    0          1       2
1    1.2        2       2
2    1.5        3       5
3    2.7        4       5
4    3.9        5       6
5    4.55       6       7
```

Desired output is;

```
     A          B       C 
0    0          1       2
1    1.2        2       3
2    1.5        3       5
3    2.7        4       5
4    3.9        5       6
5    4.55       6       8
```

I got a trouble with .25 value. I want to round up this values too. Could ypu please help me about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior)

Comment: yeah i read that, but i couldn' t understand how can apply for my dataframe column or columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use use [`numpy.floor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html) and add the boolean (`1` if `mod(1)` is `>= threshold` and `0` if its `<`):

```
threshold = 0.25
df['C'] = np.floor(df['C']) + df['C'].mod(1).ge(threshold)
```

[out]

```
      A  B    C
0  0.00  1  2.0
1  1.20  2  3.0
2  1.50  3  5.0
3  2.70  4  5.0
4  3.90  5  6.0
5  4.55  6  8.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.isclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with [`numpy.modf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html) for test `.5` for condition and round by [`numpy.ceil`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html) and [`numpy.round`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round.html) by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
threshold=0.25

s = df['C'] - threshold+0.5
print (s)
0    1.55
1    2.50
2    4.67
3    5.37
4    6.49
5    7.50
Name: C, dtype: float64

m = np.isclose(np.modf(s)[0], 0.5)

df['C']=np.where(m, np.ceil(s), np.round(s))
print (df)
      A  B    C
0  0.00  1  2.0
1  1.20  2  3.0
2  1.50  3  5.0
3  2.70  4  5.0
4  3.90  5  6.0
5  4.55  6  8.0
```

Comment: no, it' s not correct for index 3. not always round up values, it should be related to .25 threshold.