# python3.7.5: round() behaves differently in seemingly equivalent cases?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Under python 3.7.5 I execute the following code and get a weird output

```
for i in range(10):
    print(round(i+0.5))
```

[image]

If I understand correctly, any number that looks like `xxx...x.5` with any digits `x` should always round up to `xxx...x+1` under the `round()` operation, regardless whether the full integer part is even or odd. Am I making some mistake in my input? How to fix this? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: If you change `0.5` to `0.51` you will get what you want. Refer [Floating point issues in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/10825926/6997665

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you use `math` module:
replace `round` with `floor` or `ceil` as you need:

```py
from math import floor, ceil
```

now for **round down** use `floor()` and for **round up** use `ceil()`

```py
print(floor(2.9))
```

> **output:** 2

```py
print(ceil(1.1))
```

> **output:** 2