# How to compute the means of data separated by dashes with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, data-cleaning

I am trying to clean csv files so I retrieved all values which contained dashes in my ages column and I have this output

```
504       40-49
756       20-29
758       40-89
```

- I would like to have the age mean instead of recording the age range as start_age-end_age.
- I tried to compute the means but I cannot convert it to numeric, due to the dashes.
  I am expected this output :

```
504 45
756 25
```

Answer (score 3):

- To create the desired output, add `age_mean` and drop `age_range`.
- [`pandas.Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)
- [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)
- Creating the `age_mean` can be accomplished with one line of code and without creating intermediary columns.
- As per [Python 3 rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior), [`pandas.DataFrame.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) doesn't round as one would expect, so I'm leaving the final answer as a decimal.

  - `.round()` can be added as `.mean(axis=1).round()` if you want.

```py
import pandas as pd

# crate dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [504, 756, 758], 'age_range': ['40-49', '20-29', '40-89']})

|    |   id | age_range   |
|---:|-----:|:------------|
|  0 |  504 | 40-49       |
|  1 |  756 | 20-29       |
|  2 |  758 | 40-89       |

# create age_mean
df['age_mean'] = df['age_range'].str.split('-', expand=True).astype('int').mean(axis=1)

# drop age_range
df.drop(columns=['age_range'], inplace=True)

# final dataframe
|    |   id |   age_mean |
|---:|-----:|-----------:|
|  0 |  504 |       44.5 |
|  1 |  756 |       24.5 |
|  2 |  758 |       64.5 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering below to be your dataframe:

```
In [966]: df
Out[966]: 
     a    age
0  504  40-49
1  756  20-29
2  758  40-89
```

You can do this:

```
## split the `age` column into 2 columns
In [971]: df[['start_age','end_age']] = df['age'].str.split('-', expand=True) 

## convert these new columns to `int` 
In [979]: df.start_age = df.start_age.astype(int)    
In [980]: df.end_age = df.end_age.astype(int)

## Take mean of the row and round it.
In [983]: df['mean'] = df[['start_age', 'end_age']].mean(axis=1).round()
```

If you want only 2 columns, you can do this:

```
In [986]: df = df[['a', 'mean']] 
In [987]: df
Out[987]: 
Out[1010]: 
     a  mean
0  504  44.5
1  756  24.5
2  758  64.5
```