# When rounding a decimal/float to an integer, what's the difference between using round, floor or ceil in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding, floor, ceil

When trying to round a decimal point value (a float) to an integer, what is the actual difference between the `round`, `math.floor` and `math.ceil` functions in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Quick answer with examples

The difference is how they truncate and round the input.

`round` rounds towards the closest integer (breaking ties by choosing even numbers), `math.floor` rounds towards `-inf` and `math.ceil` rounds towards `+inf`.

It's also worth noting that `round(x,0)` returns a `float` while `round(x)`, `floor(x)` and `ceil(x)` return integers.

Here are a couple of examples:

| Input `(x)` | `round(x)` | `math.floor(x)` | `math.ceil(x)` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.4 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1.5 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 1.6 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| -1.4 | -1 | -2 | -1 |
| -1.5 | -2 | -2 | -1 |
| -1.6 | -2 | -2 | -1 |
| 2.5 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3.5 | 4 | 3 | 4 |
| 4.5 | 4 | 4 | 5 |
| -2.5 | -2 | -3 | -2 |
| -3.5 | -4 | -4 | -3 |
| -4.5 | -4 | -5 | -4 |

Note how `round(-1.4)` yields `-1` while `math.floor(-1.4)` yields `-2`.

Also note how `round(2.5)` yields `2` while `round(3.5)` yields `4`.

## Longer answer

### `round`

The longer explanation is that when you use `round(x)` or `round(x,0)`, Python uses a method called [round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even). The method finds the **closest integer**. In cases where the distance is the same to both larger and smaller integers, as the name suggests, the algorithm breaks the tie by choosing the closest **even** number. That's why `round(2.5)` yields `2`: because 2.5 is equally distant to 2 and 3, and in cases with two equally distant choices, the algorithm picks the even choice.

The Python documentation can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins). [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior) is also worth checking out.

### `math.floor` and `math.ceil`

On the other hand, `math.floor` and `math.ceil` explicitly take the closest integer that is smaller and larger than the input values, respectively. That's why it's said that they round "towards -/+ inf".

Take the following example: `-1.4`. In this case, the closest integer that is smaller than or equal to the input (i.e., closest to `-inf`) is -2. That's why `math.floor(-1.4)` yields `-2.0`. Similarly,  the closest integer that is larger than or equal to the input (i.e., closest to `+inf`) is -1, which is why `math.ceil(-1.4)` yields `-1`.

Here are the links to Python's documentation for [`floor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=ceil#math.floor) and [`ceil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=ceil#math.ceil)

(Credit to [@MarkDickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson) for pointing out a few mistakes in my original answer!)

Comment: It's confusing to say that "`round` rounds towards zero".  That would suggest that (for example) `1.7` would be rounded to `1` rather  than `2`. Note also that `round(some_float)` (as opposed to `round(some_float, 0)`) *does* return an integer. The "add 0.5 and truncate" description isn't accurate, either - consider what happens with `round(2.5)`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, [@MarkDickinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270986/mark-dickinson)! I agree that the original wording of "round towards zero" was confusing. Also, I hadn't noticed that the `round(2.5)` behavior was different!!! I've read up a bit more on the issue and I've edited the answer. I've also addressed the return type issues. Thanks again for the constructive feedback =)