# Python : banker's rounding

Tags: python, rounding

According to Banker's rounding, ties goes to even, for example,

round(1.25,1) -> 1.2
round(1.35,1) -> 1.4

But, in case of following rounding,

round(1.15,1) -> 1.1

It should be 1.2, why it is 1.1

Can anyone help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: Dear, my question simply is that banker's rounding behave strangly when it is given round(1.15,1). As, you can see that 1.25 its output is 1.2 (due to ties, choose even, but 1.15 is also ties, so it must be 1.2, rather 1.1)

Answer (score 0):

`float` implementation in `python` do not allow to save any fraction, so certain are saved as approximations, see [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) built-in module docs for further discussion. `python` does show it as `1.15` but in reality it is other (close) number which can be saved as float, consider following

```
print(1.15+1.15+1.15==3.45)  # False
print(1.15+1.15+1.15)  # 3.4499999999999997
```

You might use `decimal.Decimal` to prevent float-related problems as follows

```
import decimal
approx = round(decimal.Decimal("1.15"),1)
print(approx)  # 1.2
```

Note that you should use `str` as `decimal.Decimal` not `float`.

Comment: Dear, this is somthing about banker's algorith, your answer is not satisfactory.