# Python Rounding (Properly)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, rounding

For numbers like 10.5, round(10.5) gives 10. 5 should round up, not down. Is there a better built-in function.

Note:

```
    > .5 - Round up
    < .5 - Round down
```

Comment: [Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses "banker's rounding" for x.5.  Even numbers round down, odd numbers round up.  You are saying it "should" round up, but that's just your definition.  It's not the only definition.

If you always want rounding up, do:

```
result = int(x+0.5)
```