# How to round 6.25 to 6.3 and 6.24 to 6.2 in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to round 6.25 to 6.3 and 6.24 to 6.2 in Python?

The 'round' function is rounding 6.25 to 6.2:

```
mynum = 6.25
print(round(mynum, 1))
```

produces 6.2 and I really need it to produce 6.3
It seems to only round up with 6 like 6.26 produces 6.3

Just to be clear: I want 6.25 to round to 6.3 and 6.24 to round to 6.2

Comment: Also related: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/11082165)

Comment: Rounding with 5 is cultural dependant and somehow ill defined. There is no correct way to do it, just several different conventions. Could you define the expected output of the rounding function?

Comment: Python 3 default is to use "banker's rounding"... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior

Comment: @Brian Not really. `6.25` can, in fact, be represented exactly. It's the rounding algorithm used, not any imprecision in the value, that maps 6.25 to 6.2.

Comment: This works:
import decimal
newmynum = decimal.Decimal(6.25).quantize(decimal.Decimal('1.0'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
print(newmynum)