# Why does Python round 3.15 down to 3.1

Tags: python, rounding

According to Python's Banker's rounding way of rounding, it should round to an even number if it is .5 and would therefore go to 3.2. It is the same for 0.15, 1.15, 2.15 and 3.15 but 4.15 is as I would expect. Why does it do this, as banker's rounding (rounding to the even value) should mean it rounds to .2 instead of .1.

What happened:

```
>>> print(round(3.15, 1))
3.1
```

What I expected:

```
>>> print(round(3.15, 1))
3.2
```

Comment: This has some info: [Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior)

Comment: The OP understands that the python `round` function uses banker's rounding, they are asking why *apparently* for some numbers it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to floating point issues, None of the values represented by those float literals can be represented exactly in binary, so they are always slightly above or below what you wrote in the source code:

```
import decimal

floats = 0.15, 1.15, 2.15, 3.15, 4.15
for f in floats:
    print(decimal.Decimal(f))
```

You see:

```
0.1499999999999999944488848768742172978818416595458984375
1.149999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
2.149999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
3.149999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375
4.1500000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625
```

Note, if we use the exact values:

```
decimals = list(map(decimal.Decimal, ['0.15', '1.15', '2.15', '3.15', '4.15']))
for d in decimals:
    print(d, round(d, 1))
```

We get what you would expect:

```
0.15 0.2
1.15 1.2
2.15 2.2
3.15 3.2
4.15 4.2
```

We can *construct* floats that we know are representable exactly in binary (they are powers of 2):

```
exact = [(n, 2**(-n)) for n in range(1, 6)]
for exponent, f in exact:
    print(decimal.Decimal(f), round(f, exponent-1))
```

And we see now the `float` objects "work":

```
0.5 0.0
0.25 0.2
0.125 0.12
0.0625 0.062
0.03125 0.0312
```

Comment: Amusingly, your last demo doesn't demonstrate banker's rounding. All those numbers get rounded *down*.

Comment: @KellyBundy Good point. In each case, `1 - f` would be an exact binary fraction that gets rounded *up*. Maybe this could be added to the answer.

Comment: @alani I might use [odd / 8](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwEEX3c4q/TCAo6iYU3HkLcRHapB1oJ2FIQU8fjfo3b/F4v7zqkuXii7bGW8laMcWRt7ASxWcYK664M47wSFnBYIEGmaM5OXiHs31QF6mLbzAQPivKUs3/6nD70STroHmXyaSeWmrtDQ).

Comment: @KellyBundy well, they are supposed to be rounded down according to banker's rounding.

Comment: That makes sense, I didn’t realise Python couldn’t store decimals exactly, but I understand now. Thanks

Comment: @ZachTydeman this isn't something that is an issue in *Python*, it is an issue with floating point numbers

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: a good canonical reference [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) to explain why all languages running on floating-point use inexact representations.

Answer (score 0):

Read the function's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round).

[image]

Answer (score -3):

I used this function found at https://realpython.com/python-rounding/
and it returns what I expect:

```
import math
def round_up(n, decimals=0):
    multiplier = 10 ** decimals
    return math.ceil(n * multiplier) / multiplier
```

and now:

```
floats = 0.15, 1.15, 2.15, 3.15, 4.15
for f in floats:
...round_up(f,1)

0.2
1.2
2.2
3.2
4.2
```

Comment: the OP doesn't want to round up, they want banker's rounding (to the nearest even last digit). So, `0.25` should round to `0.2` not to `0.3`