# Python version issues using open

Tags: python

Are there any potential differences between Python versions using `open`. My script accepts a file, performs some calculations and outputs these calculations.

On my machine (running 2.7.1) the output is correct. On the other machine (running 2.4.6) my output is all `0.00`. Nearest I can tell, my input file isn't being opened. Is there a difference between `open()` between these versions?

Here's what my current open scheme looks like:

```
infile = open(filename, 'r')
```

An additional question: the `next(infile)` method does not skip the first line for me anymore in `2.6.4`. Does replacing `next(infile)` with `lines = infile.readlines()[1:0]` affect performance?

EDIT: CRAP THE VERSION OF THE OTHER MACHINE IS 2.4.6. Not sure how I messed that up. The original post reflects my screwup, sorry guys.

Edit2: Below is my code for reading from the file:

```
     for lines in infile:
          # do stuff with lines
     infile.close()
```

I'm guessing there's something here that may be different between 2.4.6 and 2.7.1

FINAL EDIT:

Solved my own problem guys. next(infile) is not compatible with 2.4.6 for some strange reason. I replaced it and ran my script correctly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it's unlikely to be related to the `open(..)` function, you should post the details of your calculation code (the full list of release notes is [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/tags/r27/Misc/NEWS) ). For example [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8582986/288875) mentions that `round(..)` was fixed in 2.7 .

Comment: If you have two separate questions you should ask two separate questions :). An easy way to check performance is to use `%timeit thing_to_test` in ipython...

Comment: I'm guessing it's an issue with the data file. Python didn't change that significantly between 2.6 and 2.7, and if you were using a 2.7 only feature that's not in 2.6 it would probably complain, not silently give you the wrong answer.

Comment: The version of the machine I need it to work is running 2.4.6. My apologies. An edit reflects my mistake.

Comment: @AndreHolzner a bit more code added

Comment: My guess is that you put `infile.readlines()` before the loop which exhausted the file (instead of progressing it one line like `next()`) and that's why you get `0.00` as there no lines to process (`readlines` ate them all).

Comment: I see, I see. So how can I skip the first line of a file in 2.4 and still read the file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe such changes have been made to `open`.

*Regarding the second half of your question,*

`lines = infile.readlines()[1:0]` is always `[]`, what you probably need is  `lines = infile.readlines()[1:]` instead.

And yes, using `readlines` loads the entire file (all its lines, to be precise) in memory when using `next` only reads the first line (and discards it if you don't do `some_thing = next(f)`).

If you're reading a large file, this can have an impact on performance. With a small file, it won't really make much difference.

Comment: Ack! beat me to it by a minute